# How do I "undo" undo in Github Desktop?

Tags: git, github, commit, github-desktop

I committed a working code, and was testing new code.
I accidentally clicked undo, mixing the working code and the new code.
Is there way to "undo" undo in Github Desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As illustrated [in this article](https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/14565115.html), the GitHub Desktop interface has an undo button, but no "redo" action.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsjAj.png]

If a commit has been undone, you would need to [use `git reflog` as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48285261/6309) to get it back.

Comment: concise yet great answer!